# Giving input to model in encoded format(onehotencoder)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I'm trying to give the input  to model  in encoded format.
as onehotencoder gives columns for different distinct values in origanal data.

if i give input to model like 
`clf.predict(onehotencoder.transform([['Hyderabad / Secunderabad','0 Year(s) 8 Month(s)','android,J2Ee','Nagpur','Male']])`
it is working fine..because we have columns of above inputdata.

but for new data it's not working ..

how can i solve this problem.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Does the new data contain values that is not contained in your training data?

Comment: Yes..It contains new data

Comment: No. The question is does it contain new value types. So in your training data you might have `[['Hyderabad / Secunderabad','0 Year(s) 8 Month(s)','android,J2Ee','Nagpur']]`. Notice 'Male' was left out. Then this new data has the value Male in the array. Is this the case for your data? If so. That is where the problem is.